# Potential of a capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

I'm learning about capacitors, and i cannot visualise what potential difference of the capacitor is.
I do know that  potential of a charge is work per unit charge
which is (kq)/r , where q is the charge for which we have to find the potential.

Here is how i visualise potential difference of a capacitor.

Consider a point change at X between the plates.
Then the potential difference is nothing but potential at that point due to the first plate and potential due to the second plate . And then add them up. Am i right.
I think I'm highly likely to be wrong. Please correct

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "visualize."  A capacitor separates positive and negative charges (one type accumulates on each plate).  Enforcing this separation is like stretching a spring.  If the applied voltage is removed, these charges rebalance, which is like a stretched spring  being released.

Answer (score 0):

The potential difference $V$ between two points is defined as the work $W$ required per unit charge $Q$ to move the charge between the two points.

For a capacitor the potential difference $V$ between the two plates is the work required per unit charge $Q$ to move the charge from one plate to the other via the circuit connected to the plates.

The force $F$ exerted on the charge $Q$ where $E$ is the electric field between the plates is

$$F=QE$$
$$E=V/d$$
Where $d$ is the distance between the plates. Therefore

$$F=QV/d$$

And since work $W=Fd$

$$W=QV$$
$$V=W/Q$$

Which is the definition of potential difference.

Hope this helps